# Função Tkinter sendo executada mesmo sem click no botão

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Aqui está meu código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
def add(a, b):
    messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", a.get()+b.get())
win=Tk()
win.geometry('300x200')
a=StringVar()
b=StringVar()
in1=Entry(win, textvariable=a)
in2=Entry(win, textvariable=b)
btn=Button(win, text="Somar", activebackground='green', command=add(a,b))
in1.pack()
in2.pack()
btn.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Quando executo a janela "Resultado" aparece logo mesmo não tendo clicado no botão "btn". E porque preciso importar 'messagebox' em separado mesmo já tendo importado todo módulo tkinter antes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porque você já chamou diretamente a função em:

```
btn=Button(win, text="Somar", activebackground='green', command=add(a,b))
```

o `command=` esta sendo definido com o valor do `return` do `def add` ao invés do proprio `add` em si.

Como o valor de `a` e `b` provavelmente que você deseja seja o mesmo de, basta fazer assim (já que `a` e `b` estão no escopo maior):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def add():
    messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", a.get()+b.get())

win=Tk()
win.geometry('300x200')
a=StringVar()
b=StringVar()
in1=Entry(win, textvariable=a)
in2=Entry(win, textvariable=b)
btn=Button(win, text="Somar", activebackground='green', command=add)
in1.pack()
in2.pack()
btn.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

No entanto note que `a.get()` e `b.get()` retornam strings e ao usar o sinal de 
`+` só vai concatenar, então use `int` se desejar fazer o cast para inteiro:

```
def add():
    messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", int(a.get()) + int(b.get()) )
```

ou `float` se desejar fazer o cast para flutuante, assim

```
def add():
    messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", float(a.get()) + float(b.get()) )
```